# When I press a function key on my laptop (volume, mute) it returns the keycode inside my terminal

Tags: keyboard, tty, wayland

Whenever I press a function key on my laptop the key-code gets returned (`438u`, `440u`, `439u`) on my tty emulator. I am using Arch Linux with Wayland, and my shell is `zsh`.

Any idea where I can edit this behavior and its origin?

Comment: IIRC such keymappings are handled by the display server- you didn't tell us which you were using/if you had told it about the keyboard config.

Comment: I'm using Wayland.

Comment: Does your laptop have a Blue Text `Fn` Key and is Volume.mute that same color?

Comment: it's a Thinkpad X1 Nano - volume mute is just above F1